# Cast to interface with nested interface type with generic

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I want to be able to cast a class with a generic type (which is another interface with a generic type) to it's interface but an exception is thrown.

I can cast an object with a generic type to its interface fine (see line IWrapper....) but when I try casting with an interface as a type with it's own generic type I get the error.

My thoughts are that possibly I would need to add a type constraint to the Node's type to be an `IWrapper<U>` but then it's no longer generic.

Surely if the object is of type `Node<Wrapper<object>` where node and wrapper implement interfaces then casting to `INode<IWrapper<object>>` should work fine?

Here's my SSCEE:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wrapper<object> wrapper = new Wrapper<object>();
            IWrapper<object> castedWrapper = (IWrapper<object>)wrapper; // Works fine

            var node = new Node<object>();
            node.Value = wrapper;

            INode<IWrapper<object>> castedNode = (INode<IWrapper<object>>)node;
            // Unable to cast object of type 'Test.Node`1[System.Object]' to type 'Test.INode`1[Test.IWrapper`1[System.Object]]'.
        }
    }
    class Node<T> : INode<T> 
    {
        public INode<T> Parent { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Wrapper<U> : IWrapper<U>
    {
        public U WrappedValue { get; set; }
    }

    interface INode<T>
    {
        INode<T> Parent { get; set; }
        T Value { get; set; }
    }

    interface IWrapper<U>
    {
        U WrappedValue { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try marking INode<T> as `INode<out T>` so the generic parameter is covariant (in the interface decleration)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks, I now get the error: `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'INode<T>.Parent'. 'T' is covariant.`

Comment: Covariance has some very specific rules, clearly you are breaking one. Your cast/covariance won't be valid until you bring it inline with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you are doing few things incorrectly. Let remove `var` and see what's happening.

```
Node<object> node = new Node<object>();
node.Value = wrapper;
```

This is clear that `Node<Object>` isn't of type `Node<IWrapper<object>>`. Which is why you're getting error. Since there are no constraints defined for T or U you can image doing something like casting `Node<Object>` to `Node<int>` which clearly not allowed in C#.

May be you should declare Node as:

```
Node<IWrapper<object>> node = new Node<IWrapper<object>>();
node.Value = wrapper;
```

Now the below line should work perfectly.

```
INode<IWrapper<object>> castedNode = (INode<IWrapper<object>>)node;
```

To prevent such errors you should rather use generic constraints.